# Is there any tool present in Linux to check the delivery status of any mail sent using Qmail

Tags: email

Is there any tool present in Linux to check the delivery status of any mail sent using Qmail
or looking into the log file is the only option ?

Warm Regards

Supratik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any other option for the same but you may check following link for your ref http://qmail.jms1.net/logfiles.shtml

:)

Comment: This is a good piece of information and really helps to understand the log file. After googling for sometime I found this link [http://cr.yp.to/qmailanalog.html]. The script helps to perform some of the basic analysis and also returns the delivery status of a mail sent. I hope this will help others too.